# Drupal 7 form modified after use auto save module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am strongly stuck in this point that after enabling 'save draft' module in Drupal 7,all code are disturb. After my some effort I find that there is automatically modify in Id. Below are the code with modified and not modified.

non-modified Id

```
id="edit-field-home-address-type-und-0-premise"
```

modified Id

```
id="edit-field-home-address-type-und-0-premise--2"
```

So please suggest me how to remove all these '--2' extra values from Id from Form in drupal 7.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't is a core feature on ajax callback , wrapper will be renamed. Why this is a problem for you ?

Comment: Yes, And because of this I am unable to check validation.

Comment: your JS validation ? or Backend validation ?